# React app not loading with @mui/styles package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I installed a package from the mui website and for some reason when I import "@mui/styles" I get an a error coming from my browser. This is where I installed @mui/styles from:
https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

My browser gives me 5 errors when I run my react app and it doesn't load up when I type "npm start". Here's a screenshot of the errors:
[image]
[image]

Here is the Javascript code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { db } from './firebase';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';


function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)` ,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #080',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  //useEffect: Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code runs
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      //Everytime a new post is added, this line of code activates
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id, 
        post: doc.data()
      })))
    })   //"posts" inside of firebase also everytime a document gets modified inside of post it takes a screenshot

  }, [] );   //conditions go here and there just variables 



  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      >
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <h2>I am a modal</h2>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <div className="app__header">
        <img 
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png" 
          alt="instagram_text"
        />
      </div>

      <Button></Button>

      <h1>Hello clever programmers let's build a react app!!!</h1>
      
      {
        posts.map(({id, post}) => (
          <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

'theme' in makeStyles is empty.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #080',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));
```

Instead, you should get theme by:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
const theme = createTheme()
```

complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { db } from './firebase';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';


function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)` ,
  };
}

const theme = createTheme()

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #080',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  //useEffect: Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code runs
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      //Everytime a new post is added, this line of code activates
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id, 
        post: doc.data()
      })))
    })   //"posts" inside of firebase also everytime a document gets modified inside of post it takes a screenshot

  }, [] );   //conditions go here and there just variables 



  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      >
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <h2>I am a modal</h2>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <div className="app__header">
        <img 
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png" 
          alt="instagram_text"
        />
      </div>

      <Button></Button>

      <h1>Hello clever programmers let's build a react app!!!</h1>
      
      {
        posts.map(({id, post}) => (
          <Post key={id} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me forever to figure this out. Why don't I need a theme inside of the makeStyles function?